# Typescript import .js from CDN

Tags: typescript, cdn

In my .ts file I want to reference a .js (hosted by a 3rd party) and use some of the functions in the .js file.  So far the only way I have found out how to do this is by modifying the .html page and inserting a  tag from the .ts itself.  Is there any other more elegant way of doing this apart from modifying the .html page?

Comment: https://medium.freecodecamp.com/javascript-modules-a-beginner-s-guide-783f7d7a5fcc

Comment: I am not sure how this solves my question.

Comment: You should use a module system to load your scripts. There are several such systems out there. This link explains it.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you're trying to reference some global variables that will be available at runtime, when the page loads. If you want to reference those variables, and you know what they're going to be called, you can create a definition file, and reference it in your .ts file. You're definition file might be called `ThirdParty.d.ts` and look something like this:

```
declare namespace ThirdParty {
  interface User {
    id string;
    getID(): string;
  }
}
export = ThirdParty;
```

Then you can use those declared variables, types, functions, etc from your typescript like this:

```
/// <reference path="ThirdParty.d.ts" />
var user = new ThirdParty.User("abc");
console.log(user.getID());
```

The d.ts file basically tells typescript what the types will be for your js, or untyped code that you'll be accessing.

That being said, if I was loading a third-party javascript file from a CDN, I would be cautious. Any changes to the third-party script might be incompatible with the definition file you've written, and could break your code.

Answer (score 0):

It's kind of late for this, but it can be useful for other coders.

You can create the next model in your typescript class:

```
USER = {
   NAME: {
     loadName:() => Object,
     printName:()=> {},
  }
}
```

the above code represents your model in your JS code.

The call is realized normally in your typescript class

```
excuteName() {
   this.USER.NAME.loadName();
}
```